# Launch EC2: The requested configuration is currently not supported after changing instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was using a t2.large EC2 instance. After downgrading to a t2.small (was  conecting fine) and trying to upgrade again to a t2.large or t2.medium from EC2 Instance UI I get the below error:

Error starting instances
The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

I haven't changed anything other than the instance type. Region is US Oregon.

Anyone faced this issue before? Any ideas?

Comment: After changing the instance type, make sure you go through the dialogs one by one and don't skip straight to review. The UI should throw an error on the page that has the misconfiguration.

Comment: Can you create a new instance that is of that instance class in Oregon?

Comment: Yes I can create the exact same instance class in Oregon! @mokugo-devops

Comment: I had already created the instance and was using it for a long time with the initial configurations! I was just changing the Instance Type from Actions>Instance Settings @MrDuk

Answer (score 1):

There is no one absolute answer for the issue; I faced this issue for weeks, and explored around many similar questions, all of them stating different explanations depending on the situation

- Incompatible AMIs with instance type
- Obsolete instance types
- VPC Tenancy issues

My case was **trying to create t2 instance type, with an ebs_optimized attribute, which is not supported for t2 instances**([EBS_OPTIMIZED](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html))

**Best way to troubleshoot ?**

**1.** Create an instance from the console

**2.** Create another one with same specs with APIs (Terraform/CloudFormation)

*(You will have 1 of 2 scenarios: Either the one from the console starts well and the APIs fails; Or both fails)*

**3.** (In case working from the console) Use aws-cli to describe both instances and output to 2 different files and start comparing with your own eyes (That is how I figured out the ebs_optimized thing)

In case the console is not working, it might give more informative error than the APIs.

Good luck !